# call external url in ajax and print its response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, response

I want to call a URL via AJAX and print its response. This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/api/get/1?&callback=',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log('success', result);
    },
    error: function(result) {
      console.log('fail', result);
    }
  });
</script>
```

I'm getting this error by using the above code.

> GET http://www.example.com/api/get/1?&callback=&callback=jQuery35107050195425849737_1613223910147&_=1613223910148
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: 1) You can see `callback` is added to URL twice. Once in your code, and once automatically by jQuery. Remove the one you added in the URL string. 2) The 404 error means that the URL you're calling is not found. 3) Once you've fixed that, check to ensure that the API you're calling does actually return data in JSONP format, most do not. If you've set JSONP in the hopes of working around a CORS error, then that will not work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank ou for your response, i have removed the `callback` from the url but i'm still getting the 404 error I think it is because the url is a web url not a json api url.

Comment: A 404 response would not be returned because of that. A 404 solely means that the URL you're calling does not exist.